# How to get gamma value from an image?

Tags: facebook, image, image-processing

I am working on image processing,specifically identifying gamma value from  an image.From one of your discussions i have observed the equation  `g =log(t/255)/log(a/255)` gives the gamma value.Is it possible me to identify the exact gamma value.If so,how to find out optimum `brightness (t)`.can any one give some idea to resolve this problem